# Error:CreateProcess error=193, %1 не является приложением Win32

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build

Обновил AndroidStudio до 2.2, теперь он при билде проекта выдает мне такую ошибку:

```
Gradle 'rcp_as' project refresh failed
Error:CreateProcess error=193, %1 не является приложением Win32
```

Читал по ошибке на микрософтовском сайте, не то, читал на оверфлов, там сетуют изменить методы вызова `.exe` на `.sh`. Как это исправить?

Вот строка из лога:

```
2016-09-30 11:15:43,546 [ 391968]   WARN - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask -  
2016-09-30 11:15:43,546 [ 391968]   INFO - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask - CreateProcess error=193, %1 не является приложением Win32

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 
2016-09-30 11:15:43,546 [ 391968]   INFO - ls.idea.gradle.GradleSyncState - Sync with Gradle for project 'rcp_as' failed: CreateProcess error=193, %1 не является приложением Win32

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 
2016-09-30 11:15:43,796 [ 392218]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Clearing symbols finished in 0 s. 
2016-09-30 11:15:43,796 [ 392218]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading symbols finished in 0 s. 
2016-09-30 11:15:43,796 [ 392218]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols finished in 0 s. 
2016-09-30 11:15:43,796 [ 392218]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving symbols finished in 0 s.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что **Android Studio** пытался использовать JDK/javac из папки внутри **Android Studio**, но дело в том, что мой JDK был установлен на диск **С:\Program Files\Java\%JDK%\javac.** 
**Android Studio** был установлен не на диск С:\...

По какой-то странной причине **Android Studio** упорно игнорировала уже установленный JDK.

**Решением было:**

> Удалить Android Studio, и установить на диск С:(в место по
>   умолчанию), предварительно удалив все файлы настроек из c:\Documents
>   and Settings\%USER%.AndroidStudio.

Answer (score 1):

Есть еще один способ решить "error=193, %1 не является приложением Win32" при установке "AndroidStudio 2.2" на "Win XP". Закрываете все проекты Студио до появления окна "Велком ту Андр Студ", где меню создания новых или открытия существующих проектов. Нажимаете вкладку Configure ---> Project Defaults ---> Project Structures. Убираете галочку с "Use embedded JDK", и в активизировавшемся поле вводите ссылку на папку с вашим рабочим JDK. Дальше apply, ok и вуаля.

Answer (score 1):

> По какой-то странной причине Android Studio упорно игнорировала уже установленный JDK

Android Studio не воспринимает пробелов в пути к файлам конфигурации типа 'Documents and Settings', поэтому я перенёс папку Android из 'C:\Documents and Settings\username\AppData\Local\' в папку типа 'C:\NewPlace\'.

Дальше, как было указано:

> Убираете галочку с "Use embedded JDK", и в активизировавшемся поле вводите ссылку на папку с вашим рабочим JDK.

Только после этого кнопка Apply сработала как надо.