# android studio ошибка при запуске

Tags: java, android, android-studio

> Gradle 'MyApplication' project refresh failed
>   Error:CreateProcess error=193, %1 не является приложением Win32

система стоит xp 32-разрядная. Как я понимаю это из за того что в названии папки пробелы. Но папку *Documents and Settings* переименовать нельзя, а настройки она берет оттуда и создает там дополнительные файлы.
[image: Вот такая ошибка в компиляторе]

[image: Вот куда и какие добавляет файлы андроид студио]

Comment: была похожая проблема после обновления, студия вроде подтянула свой jdk и он почему то был x64, в настройках студии укажите путь к x32 jdk

Comment: Приветствую ! Прошу посмотрите данное решение: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573670/224831

Answer (score 1):

Приветствую ! Прошу посмотрите данное решение:

Проблема в том, что Android Studio пытался использовать JDK/javac из папки внутри Android Studio, но дело в том, что JDK был установлен на диск С:\Program Files\Java\%JDK%\javac. Android Studio был установлен не на диск С:...

По какой-то странной причине Android Studio упорно игнорировала уже установленный JDK.

Решение:

Удалить Android Studio, и установить на диск С:(в место по умолчанию), предварительно удалив все файлы настроек из c:\Documents and Settings\%USER%.AndroidStudio.

Источник:

[ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573670/224831](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573670/224831)

Comment: На самом деле правильный в том источнике другой ответ

Comment: 'этот вариант я пробовал

Answer (score 0):

Установи версию 2.1.2, мне так помогло

Comment: у тебя в Documents and Settings есть какие то файлы от андр\студ?
или в какой то другой папке с пробелами в названии

Comment: У меня `Win7`, и `Android Studio` установлен на диск D,и папка называется My Documents, но проекты находятся в загрузках. У меня такая же проблема была, я прочитал, что надо старую версию установить и все помогло

Comment: спасибо. буду качать щас

Comment: Если опять такая ошибка будет, попробуйте в настройках выбрать jdk. который от Java, а не от `Android Studio`.